# CollectionViewCell image doesn't display until scrolling

Tags: xcode, asynchronous, swift3, grand-central-dispatch, image-caching

I am using this code to display image in to my customCell. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45356157/755621) is my code to fetch image from API. It was working fine as per the given link. But the problem started when I added this code to my  `cellForItemAt indexPath:` for image Cache.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // Displaying other elements with text

    customCell.mainImage.image = nil

    var image1 = self.imageCache.object(forKey: indexPath.item as AnyObject) as? UIImage

        if (image1 == nil) {
            self.ImageFetcher(postId: self.myArray[indexPath.item].id!, completion: { (image) in
            image1 = image
            self.imageCache.setObject(image1!, forKey: indexPath.item as AnyObject)
        })
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        customCell.mainImage.image = image1
    }
}
```

Above code works fine without any error but, not displaying/loading images until I scroll the collectionView up and down. Don't understand what I am missing here. Any help would be appreciated !!

Comment: `image1 = image` => `DispatchQueue.main.async { customCell.mainImage.image = image }`

Comment: I tried adding `customCell.mainImage.image = image` in  `ImageFetcher` but then cell displays wrong images and then changes to correct image again when scrolling fast.

Comment: The reason why it's displaying the wrong image is because you didn't cancel the previous image load when the cell is being reused.

Comment: I did try `override func prepareForReuse() {
        mainImage.image = nil
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }` in my customCell class but, no difference!

Comment: @Snehal i think your imageFetcher function in not good

Comment: @Snehal use UIIMageView extension for more effective use

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // Displaying other elements with text

    if let image1 = self.imageCache.object(forKey: indexPath.item as AnyObject) as? UIImage
    {
        customCell.mainImage.image = image1
    }
    else {
        self.ImageFetcher(postId: self.myArray[indexPath.item].id!, completion: { (image) in
            self.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: indexPath.item as AnyObject)
            customCell.mainImage.image = image1
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> STEP:1 Create extension of uiimageview to download image from url, and if already downloaded then from cache

```
   let imageCache = NSCache()
    extension UIImageView {

    func loadImageUsingCacheWithURLString(url: NSURL) {

        self.image = nil

        // First check if there is an image in the cache
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.objectForKey(url) as? UIImage {

            self.image = cachedImage

            return
        }

        else {
        // Otherwise download image using the url location in Google Firebase
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            }
            else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    // Cache to image so it doesn't need to be reloaded every time the user scrolls and table cells are re-used.
                    if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                        imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: url)
                        self.image = downloadedImage

                    }
                })
            }
            }).resume()
        }

    }
```

> STEP 2 : Usage

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // Displaying other elements with text
    customCell.mainImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithURLString(url: yoururl)
 }
```